# Is there query equivalent for EntityManager.getReference()?

Tags: jpa, jpql

In JPA there is a method EntityManager.getReference() that doesn't actually load anything from database but returns a proxy (see e.g.: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607532/when-to-use-entitymanager-find-vs-entitymanager-getreference) ) that will be loaded up only when necessary.

What if I would like to have a query that returns list of references instead of loading real objects from database? Is there equivalent for queries?

Comment: Queries mostly have to go to the database, so what purpose is there not loading the basic data at the same time?  Use of proxies with getReference is provider specific, so your provider may have options for regular queries and even querying only in memory.  Marking basic relationships as lazy, coupled with JPA 2.1's EntityGraph can allow your queries to only return exactly the data you need and leave the rest unfetched.

Comment: @Chris Thanks! Could you please convert it to an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of proxies with getReference is provider specific, so your provider may have options for regular queries and even querying only in memory. Marking basic relationships as lazy, coupled with JPA 2.1's EntityGraph can allow your queries to only return exactly the data you need and leave the rest unfetched.