# Find out whether entity exists by id

Tags: jpa

This excellent question and answer define when to use [`EntityManager#find` v. `#getReference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607532/when-to-use-entitymanager-find-vs-entitymanager-getreference) with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1608621/409976).

This question elaborates on the behavior of getting, and then updating an object.

But, I'm only interested in determining whether my `javax.persistence.Entity` exists for a particular id.

Is `EntityManager#getReference` more efficient than `EntityManager#find`?

I'm looking for the light-weight way to find whether an `id` exists for a given Entity.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own utility class for that, with a query like:

```
SELECT id FROM EntityClass where id= ?
```

and then simply call `query.getSingleResult()` trying/catching a `NoResultException`for the case no result is available (or `query.getResultList()` and checking the `count()`).

Selecting the ID only makes sure, that the minimal needed data is fetched from DB, instead of fully fetching the entity with its related entities.