# Do we have something similar to Hibernate's load method when we are using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

As per definition hibernate's **"load()"** method always retrieves proxy objects.

In my current project I am using JPA and ORM provider being used is hibernate. 
How can I achieve load() functionality (provided by Session) while using EntityManager (JPA)?

Comment: entity managet find ?

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607532/when-to-use-entitymanager-find-vs-entitymanager-getreference

Comment: Thanks.. EntityManager.getReference() solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you want is [EntityManager.getReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29)