# Sometime getting org.hibernate.StaleStateException when calling delete after update

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-xml-mapping

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException
```

Is thrown sometimes (not consistent) in unit test case.

The normal flow is:

1. Create
2. Update
3. Delete

StaleStateException is thrown while executing delete operation.

The entity has child entities with one to many relationship:

```
<set name="child" cascade="delete, all,delete-orphan" inverse="true"
      lazy="true">
      <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
      <key column="COLUMN"/>
      <one-to-many class="CHILDClass"/>
    </set>
```

And the cache strategy is **"nonstrict-read-write"**

Not sure of its issue due to second level cache, as the exception is not consistent.
How to fix this issue and what extra details I need to check to fix this issue.

Comment: Add the full stack trace

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBeikov for reply, I dont have the complete stack now, will try to update the question.
Just one link I found here is that it is due to the cache strategy,
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-nonstrict_read_write-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/

Comment: Usually `StaleStateException` means that you are trying to manage an instance with Hibernate that has not been attached to the Session. See if this answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44933587/batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count-from-update-0/44997468#44997468