# Hibernate/JPA, save a new entity while only setting id on @OneToOne association

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two entities,

```
  class A { @OneToOne B b; } 

  class B { ... lots of properties and associations ... }
```

When I create **new A()** and then save, i'd like to only set the id of b.

So **new A().setB(new B().setId(123))**.

Then **save** that and have the database persist it.

I do not really need to or want to fetch the entire B first from the database, to populate an instance of A.

I remember this used to work, but when I am testing it is not.

I have tried **Cascade All** as well.

Comment: I don't think it will work if you don't fetch B entity first and set it to A at least while  using JPQL

Comment: I think what you're looking for is lazy loading.

Comment: @zerocool You mean on B's assoications? Or \@OneToOne in A on b ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B b = (B) hibernateSession.byId(B.class).getReference(b.getId());
a.setB(b);

hibernateSession.load(...) // can also be used as it does the same.
```

The JPA equivalent is :

```
 entitymanager.getReference(B.class, id)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607532/when-to-use-entitymanager-find-vs-entitymanager-getreference

Answer (score -2):

Below code should help.It will fetch B only when its accessed.

`class A {
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) B b; 
}`