# Why Lazy Collections do not work with JavaFX getters / setters?

Tags: jpa, javafx, eclipselink, lazy-loading

I experienced poor performance when using `em.find(entity, primaryKey)`.
The reason seems to be that `em.find()` will also load entity collections, that are annotated with `FetchType.LAZY`.

This small test case illustrates what I mean:

```
public class OriginEntityTest4 {

    [..]    

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
    final OriginEntity oe = new OriginEntity("o");
    final ReferencePeakEntity rpe = new ReferencePeakEntity();
    oe.getReferencePeaks().add(rpe);
    DatabaseAccess.onEntityManager(em -> {
        em.persist(oe);
        em.persist(rpe);
    });
    System.out.println(rpe.getEntityId());
    DatabaseAccess.onEntityManager(em -> {
        em.find(OriginEntity.class, oe.getEntityId());
    });

    }

}

@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Entity(name = "Origin")
public class OriginEntity extends NamedEntity {

    [..]

    private final ListProperty<ReferencePeakEntity> referencePeaks =
    referencePeaks =
    new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(ReferencePeakEntity.extractor()));

    @Override
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "origin", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public final List<ReferencePeakEntity> getReferencePeaks() {
    return this.referencePeaksProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setReferencePeaks(final List<ReferencePeakEntity> referencePeaks) {
    this.referencePeaksProperty().setAll(referencePeaks);
    }

}
```

I cannot find any documentation on that, my question is basically how can I prevent the EntityManager from loading the lazy collection?

Why I need `em.find()`?

I use the following method to decide whether I need to persist a new entity or update an existing one.

```
public static void mergeOrPersistWithinTransaction(final EntityManager em, final XIdentEntity entity) {

    final XIdentEntity dbEntity = em.find(XIdentEntity.class, entity.getEntityId());
    if (dbEntity == null) {
        em.persist(entity);
    } else {
        em.merge(entity);
    }
    }
```

Note that `OriginEntity` is a JavaFX bean, where getter and setter delegate to a `ListProperty`.

Comment: Your Set method doesn't work well with a lazy field, as it will need to traverse and fetch the collection to add it as a part of the this.referencePeaksProperty().setAll(referencePeaks) method.  Why are you not just storing it locally as a List?

Comment: Thanks so much! This was the problem. I updated the question. Apparently calling `ListProperty.setAll()` will iterate over all elements.

Answer (score 1):

Because FetchType.LAZY is only a hint. Depending on the implementation and how you configured your entity it will be able to do it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to titles question but maybe to your problem.

You can use also `em.getReference(entityClass, primaryKey)` in this case. It should be more efficient in your case since it just gets a reference to possibly existing entity.

See [When to use EntityManager.find() vs EntityManager.getReference()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607532/when-to-use-entitymanager-find-vs-entitymanager-getreference)

On the other hand i think your check is perhaps not needed. You could just persist or merge without check?

See [JPA EntityManager: Why use persist() over merge()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge)

Comment: Maybe just merge, I am not sure. Persist will write always write a new entry to db.

Comment: @kerner1000 do some benchmarking and tell me the results :)