# Does JpaRepository has a patch method to update a specific object

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to know if JpaRepository has a method to update only a specific value of an object without getting the whole object from the database. This is my code to explain it a bit more:

**Controller**

```
@PatchMapping("/{labelKeyUuid}")
@ApiOperation("Update the current version of an existing label key")
fun updateCurrentVersion(@PathVariable labelKeyUuid: UUID,
                         @RequestBody labelValueUuidRequest: LabelValueUuidRequest) {
    val labelValue = labelValueService.findByUuid(labelValueUuidRequest.uuid)
            ?: throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Label value with uuid '\'${labelValueUuidRequest.uuid}\'' not found")
    return labelKeyService.updateCurrentVersion(labelKeyUuid, labelValue)
}
```

**Service**

```
fun findByUuid(uuid: UUID) : LabelValueEntity? {
    return labelValueRepository.findByIdOrNull(uuid)
}

fun updateCurrentVersion(labelKeyUuid: UUID, labelValue: LabelValueEntity) {
    labelKeyRepository.save(labelValue, labelKeyUuid)
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
interface LabelKeyRepository : JpaRepository<LabelKeyEntity, UUID>
```

JpaRepository has save(entity) method. I know i can work around it by getting the object from the database and set the labelValue with the new one and save it to the database. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: JPQL has an [`UPDATE` statement](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage004.html#BNBTK). Other than this, as long as an [entity is still managed](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/persistence-intro004.html#BNBRC), you can modify an entity and when the transaction is commited, the changes on the entity will be persisted in the database.

Comment: A faster way would be to not save it to the database: modifying a managed entity, inside a transaction, makes the changes automatically persistent. No need to call save().

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t need to access current state of the object, you can use `entityManager.getReference()` method. Contrary to `entityManager.find()` this method won’t invoke a select statement.

`entityManager.getReference()` is exposed on `JPARepository` as `getOne()` method.

Note that objects returned by both methods have automatic dirty checking, you should call `find()` or `getReference()` and subsequent modifications in a same transaction, and the changes will be automatically persisted. Use `save()` on the repository only to persist new entities or attach detached entities.

Read also:
[When to use EntityManager.find() vs EntityManager.getReference() with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607532/when-to-use-entitymanager-find-vs-entitymanager-getreference-with-jpa/50945279)